# PHP - pagination count incorrectly

Tags: php, pagination

So I have a simple pagination system on my website. But there's a problem with my calculation for the next page. whenever the page is on page 2 the next page is 13 instead of 3. I have tested the calculation and it always comes out with 3 as result. Here is my code:

```
                            <?php
                             $applied_filters = array("parent" => null, "child" => null);

if(isset($_GET['cat'])) {
    $applied_filters["parent"] = $_GET['cat'];
    if(isset($_GET['sub']))
        $applied_filters["child"] = $_GET['sub'];
}

if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
} else {
    $page = 1;
}

$products_per_page = 9;
$start_from = ($page-1) * $products_per_page;

                            $pagination_url = "winkel.php?";
                            if($applied_filters["parent"] != null) {
                                $pagination_url .= "cat=" . $applied_filters["parent"];

                                if($applied_filters["child"] != null) {
                                    $pagination_url .= "&sub=" . $applied_filters["child"] . "&page=";
                                } else {
                                    $pagination_url .= "&page=";
                                }
                            } else {
                                $pagination_url .= "page=";
                            }
                            echo $page . '<br>'; // shows 2
                            $nextpage = $page + 1; //shows 3
                            echo $nextpage;
                        ?>

                        <ul class="pagination">
                            <?php if($page > 1) { ?>
                            <li><a href="<?= $pagination_url .= $page - 1; ?>">&laquo;</a>
                            </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <li class="active"><a href="#"><?= $page ?></a>
                            </li>
                            <?php if($page < $max_pages) { echo $nextpage; // shows 3?>
                            <li><a href="<?= $pagination_url .= $nextpage; // shows 13 ?>">&raquo;</a>
                            </li>
                            <?php } ?>
```

I also have some URL code for the filters on my website:

```
                <?php
                // link filters
                if(isset($_GET['cat'])) {
                    if(isset($_GET['cat']) && isset($_GET['sub'])) {
                        if($_GET['cat'] != "alles")
                            $result_products = $db->get_by_cat("products", $_GET['cat'], $_GET['sub'], $start_from, $products_per_page);
                    } else if (isset($_GET['cat'])) {
                        if($_GET['cat'] != "alles")
                            $result_products = $db->get_by_cat("products", $_GET['cat'], null, $start_from, $products_per_page);
                    }     
                }

                if(isset($_POST['clearbrand'])) {
                    unset($_POST['brandfilter']);
                    unset($_POST['applybrand']);
                }

                $filtered_brands = null;
                if(isset($_POST['brandfilter'])) $filtered_brands = $_POST['brandfilter'];

                // form filters
                if(isset($_POST['applybrand'])) {
                    if(isset($_GET['cat'])) {
                        $result_products = $db->get_by_checkbox("products", "brand", $_POST['brandfilter'], $_GET);
                    } else {
                        $result_products = $db->get_by_checkbox("products", "brand", $_POST['brandfilter']);
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

So, does anybody know why my pagination counts from 2 to 13?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well the fact that you are constantly _appending_ stuff to `$pagination_url` might have something to do with it, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
<?php if($page > 1) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?= $pagination_url .= $page - 1; ?>">&laquo;</a></li>
<?php } ?>
<li class="active"><a href="#"><?= $page ?></a></li>
<?php if($page < $max_pages) { echo $nextpage; // shows 3?>
    <li><a href="<?= $pagination_url .= $nextpage; // shows 13 ?>">&raquo;</a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

If `$page` is greater than 1 (which it is on page 2), you add `$page - 1` to the `$pagination_url`, basically putting a "1" at the end.

Then, in the second `if` statement, if `$page` is less than `$max_pages`, you **also** add `$nextpage` (which is 3) to the `$pagination_url`, putting a "3" after the "1" you added before. Therefore, `$pagination_url` will now have "13" at the end.

You'll want to change this to:

```
<?php if($page > 1) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?= $pagination_url . ($page - 1); ?>">&laquo;</a></li>
<?php } ?>
<li class="active"><a href="#"><?= $page ?></a></li>
<?php if($page < $max_pages) { echo $nextpage; // shows 3?>
    <li><a href="<?= $pagination_url . $nextpage; // shows 13 ?>">&raquo;</a></li>
<?php } ?>
```